# Blackberry Midlet Install Notify

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, midlet

I want to be notified on Install/Delete of my blackberry app(cod). Something similar to the Midlet-Install-Notify JAD property. For now, it seems blackberry doesn't support this JAD property. Is there an alternative for blackberry? If not are there any tips/tricks I can use to know when my app is installed (without putting it in source code)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [post on the BB forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Cleanup-files-on-application-uninstall/td-p/545936) that points to a way to do this with `CodeModuleManager`. Basically, you need to set up a background process that registers itself as a CodeModuleListener. The background process needs to be running, of course, to receive notifications.